# Is the construction "maker of all universe" grammatical in any English dialect?

Tags: grammar, dialects

The song "Great Are You Lord" by the worship musician [Sinach](http://www.christembassy.org/music/sinach2/home.html) includes the following lines:

> Holy, Holy God Almighty
>   It’s a privilege to worship you
>   **Maker of all universe**
>   It’s an honour just to stand before you

I'm aware that the highlighted line above ("Maker of all universe") isn't grammatical in British English (my native dialect). As Sinach is Nigerian, I'm guessing that [Nigerian English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigerian_English) is her native dialect - is this construction grammatical in that dialect, or indeed in any others?

Comment: It's poetry. All sorts of grammatical license is found.

Comment: @bib That’s a bit too facile for my tastes. The answer that the OP is looking for is that no, it is not grammatical in any English dialect; it sounds alien to drops the article there. It’s not like the maker of all sunshine.

Comment: Yes, it is, in standard English. Why the question? How is that not grammatical in British English? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Would standard English not be "Maker of all of the universe" ?

Comment: @mplungjan: Indeed, I'm pretty sure it requires the article in British English. "Universes" are a discrete quantity, unlike "sunshine" (cf. tchrist above), so "Maker of all universes" or "Maker of all the universe" would both be correct. It could be poetic license, but I'd expect that only when it makes the phrase more beautiful - to my ear, as constructed it sounds really clunky.

Comment: @mplungjan No. There are standard English use cases from respected authors/ authorities/ other sources. *all universe* = *all of the universe.* A standard dictionary would do.

Comment: @Kris a link would be great. Many NGRAM entries are of Indian origin

Comment: Slightly better standard English would be *"Maker of all the universe"*. Using two *"of"s* here is unnecessary, and it sounds better without the repetition.

Comment: @kris I did an ngram search and went through some of these references. Most of these are not really the phrase "all universe" but there's some other punctuation in there, like "it is part of the all, universe". A couple had "stars in the (something something parenthesis ALL) universe". A few mentioned an "All-Universe Competition". There were several that had numerous grammar problems of which "all universe" was just one. There do appear to be some Indian metaphysical books that talk about "all universe", so perhaps this is an accepted usage in Indian English.

Comment: @Jay Do not use nGrams in such cases as this. Use them to substantiate what has already been stated. Use them best for collocations and idiomatic expressions.

Answer (score 2):

It wouldn't be considered grammatically correct in American English either.

"Universe" is a countable noun, even though we normally think of there being just one. Here it's used in the singular, so it requires an article (or one of the adjectives that can take the place of an article). The conventional thing to write would have been "maker of the universe". If the "all" is considered essential, she could have said "maker of all the universe" or "maker of the whole universe".

Songs and poems don't always follow strict grammatical rules for a variety of reasons, including the need to put a particular word at the end of a line to make a rhyme, or to have the right number of syllables in a line to give the correct rhythm. But I don't see the need here. If she had said "maker of the universe" it would have expressed the same idea and been the same number of syllables.

I suppose she could also have said "make of all universes" if she thinks there is more than one.

All around this is puzzling. I suppose if, as you say, the writer is Nigerian, there could be different usage in Nigerian English. I don't think I've ever spoken to a Nigerian. Well, except for the emails I'm always getting about the millions of dollars they want to give me. I should go back and study the grammar in those.

Comment: I daresay studying Nigerian e-mails about fiscal ventures would likely give you the impression that absolutely _anything_ is grammatical in Nigerian English, or indeed that Nigerian English is a misnomer for something that is not English at all.

Comment: Not related to the original question, but this brings up the thought: If your child asks why he should study grammar, one answer is: So you can recognize spam emails. If you get an email that claims to be from a big company or the government, and it contains multiple grammar errors, it is almost surely fake. Every now and then a big organization will send out an email that has a grammar error, but very rarely more than one.